# Can we know how many people are subscribed to a user's RSS feed?

Tags: feature-request, feed, subscription

I noticed you can "follow" users by subscribing to their rss feed, is it possible to know how many subscribers each user has next to it's subscribe button?

On a side note, are rss feeds commonly used? I wonder...

Comment: I don't see how this can work - many people use feedreader webapps that store RSS aggregations on the server. How does SO know which user asked for the feed?

Comment: yeah... this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2456/are-there-any-statistics-kept-on-rss-feeds?rq=1 says the much the same... but hell, they got great engeneers a SO, maybe they can come out with a way. I'm sure it can be done (user ids for logged in user on the url, ip addresses, etc.), the real question is, is it worth the effort? the only way to know if people are interested in this.